# Remove item from state

Tags: reactjs

I know this question has been asked a lot but I haven't seem to find a solution even tho I've tried different scenarios.

```js
this.state = {
      chartTypes: [{name: 'Bar', id: 1},{name: 'Line', id: 2},{name: 'Pie', id: 3},{name: 'Radar', id: 4} ],
      selectedChart: [],
}

  onSelect = (selectedList, selectedItem) => {
   // selectedItem.name returns name of chartTypes, selectedItem.id returns id of chartTypes.

    this.setState({
      selectedChart: selectedItem.name
    })
  }
  
  onRemove = (selectedList, removedItem) => {
       // removedItem.name returns name of chartTypes, removedItem.id returns id of chartTypes.
  }
```

The select option works fine but I just put it there so you can have a better understanding. `onSelect` puts every `selectedItem.name` into `selectedChart`. On the remove function, how may I remove item from `this.state.selectedChart` based on the value/index.

Comment: what do you mean remove state.selectedChart based on the value? your selectedChart is an object, not an array.

Comment: @AkinoArchilles `selectedChart` is an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = this.state.selectedChart.filter((el)=> 
  el.id !==removedItem.id
);
```

after filter

```
this.setState({selectedChart:newArray})
```

Comment: I need the `selectedChart` not the `chartTypes`. `chartTypes` is the variable which contains the chart types/models.

Comment: @ClaytonCrockville 
That I will understand
You want to  the ``removedItem`` from the ``selectedList``
And put it inside the ``state.selectedChart``?

Comment: onSelect adds what you select to `this.state.selectedChart`. onRemove is supposed to take out of `this.state.selectedChart` on what user has clicked to remove.  https://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1473/1143598225.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
    let temp = this.state.selectedChart;
    temp=temp.filter((item) => item !== removedItem.name);
    this.setState({ selectedChart: temp });
```

Comment: TypeError: temp.filter is not a function

Comment: if the this.state.selectedChart is a string and only one string can be set at a time ?

Answer (score 0):

Just filter and set backed to state

```
onRemove = (selectedList, removedItem) => {
      let filtered = this.state.chartTypes.filter(list=> list.id !==removedItem.id);
      this.setState({ chartTypes: filtered });
  }
```

Comment: I tried adding state by `    this.setState({selectedChart: filtered})` but it doesn't give the correct result.

Comment: @ClaytonCrockville in you onRemove function just pass single array object...and set back to chartTypes not selectedChart